# Regular Expression to match only whitespace

Tags: ruby, regex, whitespace

How can I write a regular expression that matches whitespace only?

I have a Ruby application that allows me to match my email subject and body based on regular expressions.  I do not have access to the code.

I am trying to take action on empty email bodies.  The regex should match if an email body contained all newlines and space characters. It would not match if there was a single alphanumeric character.  The regex should allow whitespace at the start and and of the email body.

The following email body would not be matched. I've highlighted it to show the line breaks.

[image: Imgur image of email body]

The following email body would be matched.

[image: Imgur image of email body]

I've tried various things using Rubular

The best I can get is `^\s*$` but this matches newlines.

Comment: I thought you said you wanted to match newlines?

Comment: I would recommend that you post and example of the email you want to match and the ones you want to skip.

Comment: Is that what I said?  I could match a newline with single RegEx but what about the other conditions?

Comment: @TroyWitthoeft: Thanks, but please do not link to images of text. Just paste it into the question, it's not too long.

Comment: @Bergi Would you mind showing me how to post code that includes linebreaks at the top?  The auto-formatter eats them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean, but this is a regex that matches strings that include only whitespaces:

```
/\A\s*\z/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say sawa has what you want but it's simpler to negate it:

```
str !~ /\S/ # true if str contains no non-whitespace chars
str !~ /\w/ # true if str contains no alphanumeric chars (plus _)
```

Comment: I can't use code.  So I can't use `str !~` to check for an inverse of a RegEx.  But these expressions may come in handy, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No regex:

```
p "  \n  \t".strip.empty? #=> true
```

Comment: What does "Can't use code" mean? You aren't allowed to program a solution and have to print it and use scissors to cut the offending lines out of the page? How 60's.

Comment: It's not a time machine, it's just that the registry input is exposed through the application.  I'm working with an application, and I can't edit the application code.   Thanks for the suggestions though!